# In Scala, how to read a simple CSV file having a header in its first line?

Tags: parsing, scala, file-io, csv

The task is to look for a specific field (by it's number in line) value by a key field value in a simple CSV file (just commas as separators, no field-enclosing quotes, never a comma inside a field), having a header in its first line.

User uynhjl has given an example (but with a different character as a separator):

```
val src = Source.fromFile("/etc/passwd")
val iter = src.getLines().map(_.split(":"))
// print the uid for Guest
iter.find(_(0) == "Guest") foreach (a => println(a(2)))
// the rest of iter is not processed
src.close()
```

the question in this case is how to skip a header line from parsing?

Comment: I have just written a question and comprehensive answer covering both parsing the input and then composing the output for a CSV file. It's located here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32488453/501113

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can just use `drop`:

```
val iter = src.getLines().drop(1).map(_.split(":"))
```

From the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html):

> `def   drop  (n: Int)  : Iterator[A]`:
>   Advances this iterator past the first
>   *n* elements, or the length of the
>   iterator, whichever is smaller.

Comment: It is **not correct way to read CSV file**. "Parsing CSV files properly is not a trivial matter", see **[CSV specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification)** and next answer.

Comment: @PeterKrauss While the title focuses on the CSV part, the question itself makes it clear that what the user is trying to do is skip a line.

Comment: Sorry Travis, it is not a bold for you, it is for the  48k pageviews people that lost time looking for general "CSV solution".  Seems a problem of Scala standard libraries, there are no standard... But it is used for big data-centric projects (e.g. Spark) and there are no obvious CSV reader.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a [CSV reader in Scala](http://gist.github.com/115557). Yikes.

Alternatively, you can look for a [CSV reader in Java](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/), and call that from Scala.

Parsing CSV files properly is not a trivial matter.  Escaping quotes, for starters.

Comment: I've seen this, but looks too complex for my simple case. I don't need all those regexps as my files are very simple.

Comment: I've just posted a way simpler solution (which is easily copy/pasted right into the local coding context) on this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32488453/501113

Comment: This should be a comment at best, since it doesn't address the question (how to skip a row).

Answer (score 4):

First I read the header line using `take(1)`, and then the remaining lines are already in `src` iterator. This works fine for me.

```
val src = Source.fromFile(f).getLines

// assuming first line is a header
val headerLine = src.take(1).next

// processing remaining lines
for(l <- src) {
  // split line by comma and process them
  l.split(",").map { c => 
      // your logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with `split(",")` is that when you come across a string like `"This, that"`, it splits it too even though it's the part of a single point.

Comment: I just addressed the very common and erroneous "use split(",") advice in my comprehensive answer to a CSV question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32488453/501113

Comment: The question says `simple CSV`. If CSV is not simple, it is always better to us a dedicated CSV library.