# Not able to get rid of quotation marks in my regex

Tags: regex, scala

I wrote this regex

```
val regex = """(?<=,|^)(((?:")([^"]*)(?:"))([^,]*))""".r
```

If I give an input line of

```
val input = "\"FOO,BAR\",\"10,1\",12,This is Test,X,X"
```

Now if I do

```
regex.findAllIn(input).matchData.foreach(println)
```

I can see

```
"FOO,BAR"
"10,1"
12
This is Test
X
X
```

My question is that in the Regex Above. I had clearly put the `"` in the non capturing Group by doing `(?:")` So the output token should have been `FOO,BAR` and not `"FOO,BAR"`.

Why didn't the non-capture group work as expected?

Edit: Based on one of the comment below that non-capture group are still being matched and consumed. I tried to rewrite the expression as

```
@ val regex = """(?<=,|^)(((?<=")([^"]*)(?="))|([^,]*))""".r
```

but now it breaks altogether because the first part of the OR expression never matches and the output is

```
"FOO
BAR"
"10
1"
12
This is Test
X
X
```

So now its only matching the second condition of `[^,]*`

I also googled and found this thread

[Parsing CSV input with a RegEx in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441556/parsing-csv-input-with-a-regex-in-java)

But the accepted answer has the same problem as the one I have above

What I want to see as the output of the expression is

```
FOO,BAR
10,1
12
This is Test
X
X
```

Comment: It works as expected. Non-capturing parts are not captured, but still matched and *consumed*.

Comment: Just because the non-capturing group is inside a capturing group.

Comment: Please explain what you need to match in words.

Comment: Do not parse CSV with just one regex. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614041/in-scala-how-to-read-a-simple-csv-file-having-a-header-in-its-first-line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted, but it appears to work.

```
val regex = """(?<=,|^)("([^"]*)"|([^,]*))""".r
val input = "\"FOO,BAR\",\"10,1\",12,This is Test,X,X"

regex.findAllMatchIn(input).map{m => 
  Option(m.group(2)) getOrElse m.group(0)
}.foreach(println)
```

I have to agree that Regex is not well suited for CSV parsing.